# Change QWidget Title Color

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a **custom class called Window that extends QWidget**.

```
#include "window.h"

// This is the base that all (MDI) sub-windows extend off

Window::Window()
{
    // Add fake icon to remove icon in all
    setWindowIcon(QIcon("."));
}

void Window::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
 }
```

css:

```
QWidget:title
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #ca0619);
}
```

When I do this **the buttons (minimize, maximize and close) disappear** (as seen in the picture below).

[image]

So my question, **how do I properly style my Window titlebar**?

Comment: style it in the constructor by  `this->setStyleSheet();` and forget about css?

Comment: perhaps you could use `this->styleSheet()` on a default QWindow to see what are you missing?

Comment: @user3528438 this did not work, if I did: QWidget
{
    background-color: black
}
it would work but then if I do QWidget:title , nothing happens.

Comment: Don't think it's possible to style a window titlebar in a platform independent way with Qt. It's not really supported and results may vary. As far as I can tell applications with styled titlebars tend to be frameless windows with custom code to handle all drawing and input normally handled by the window frame.

Comment: ^-- Is true. Here's an example. https://github.com/LMMS/lmms/issues/2450